# Python Class Script Running Errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a class using Python 2.7.9 and it keeps running into errors.

Here is my script:

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, name):

        self.health=50
    def eat(self, food):
        if(food=='apple'):
            self.health+=10
self.name=Jeff
Jeff=Hero('Jeff')

def introduce(self, name):
    print Jeff.name

def checkAtt():
    print Jeff.health

introduce()
```

It keeps saying `name 'Jeff' is not defined`.

Comment: Please edit your question and indent it accordingly.

Comment: Is the error that `Jeff` isn't defined, or that `Jeff.name` isn't defined?

Comment: please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has numerous problems. The first, that is causing the specific error, is that you attempt to assign:

```
self.name = Jeff
```

before you have defined either `self` or `Jeff`. `self` is conventionally only used inside instance methods (like your `Hero.eat`), where it is the name of the first parameter.

---

Secondly, your `Hero.__init__` doesn't actually assign the `name` parameter to the `name` attribute; it should look like:

```
class Hero(object): # Note inheritance from 'object' for new-style class

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name # Note assignment of instance attribute
        self.health = 50

    ...
```

`jeff = Hero("Jeff")` will call `Hero.__init__`, creating new `Hero` instance, setting its `name` attribute to `"Jeff"` (and `health` attribute to `50`) and assigning that instance to the name `jeff`.

---

Thirdly, you have two standalone functions (`introduce` and `checkAtt`) that should probably also be instance methods:

```
def Hero(object):

    ...

    def introduce(self):
        print self.name

...

jeff = Hero("Jeff")
jeff.introduce() # equivalent to 'Hero.introduce(jeff)'
```

or, if remaining as standalone functions, take a single parameter, the `Hero` instance to operate on (which should *not* be called `self`, again by convention) - there is not much point writing a function that only works if it's run in a scope where the name `Jeff` is available!

```
class Hero(object):

    ...

def introduce(hero):
    print hero.name

jeff = Hero("Jeff")
introduce(jeff)
```

**Note the indentation** in these two different cases - it is very important in Python. Also, note the different ways of calling `introduce` depending on whether it's an instance method or a function.

---

I suggest you read [the tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) and [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).